# ZeroMQ informing clients about each other

Tags: zeromq

i want to parallelize a heavy computing task across several workercomputers, where these workers have to share data between each other. I have a server to which all the workers connect and get informed about their "neighbors", so that they can connect to them and exchange the data. Here is a picture of the structure i had in mind:
[image: system structure]

As you can see every node will have 4 neighbours (i didn't want to draw more in the picture). I'm not fixed at all at the socket types, i just figured they would be the best to choose.

But it seems that ZeroMQ has no way to convey connection information about one connection to another. Since i think this is actually a quite common task, there must be a solution to this.
The type of of network can vary, it can be a standard tcp/ip network with just a bunch of computers linked via a router, or a cluster connected via infiniband. So basically what i want is a string i can simply insert at one client into the connect() or bind() and not have to worry about protocols and network types and all that stuff - which is as i understand exactly what zeromq tries to accomplish.

Thanks for your answers in advance! :)

edit: Here is an examplary communication i had in mind:

```
WorkerMiddle.sendToServer("Hey server, please tell me my neighbours")
Server.sendToWorkerMiddle(Worker.top.connectionInfo())
WorkerMiddle.connectTo(WorkerTop)
Server.sendToWorkerMiddle(Worker.bottom.connectionInfo())
WorkerMiddle.connectTo(WorkerBottom)
Server.sendToWorkerMiddle(Worker.left.connectionInfo())
WorkerMiddle.connectTo(WorkerLeft)
Server.sendToWorkerMiddle(Worker.right.connectionInfo())
WorkerMiddle.connectTo(WorkerRight)
```

Comment: This is extremely broad, no useful answer can be given without more information. So, first of all [read the docs](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all), they are extremely informative and include *many* connection patterns to accomplish the sort of thing you're looking for. In order to provide more useful information, provide some code that indicates a) the topology of your network (physically, how is it laid out/connected together b) the protocol you're using c) what type of sockets you're using (pub/sub, rep/req, etc) d) who is binding and who is connecting, and how are the endpoints named

Comment: Thanks Jason, i already did. But that is really all i can say, because i would choose the socket types according to what somebody offers as an solution. But i'll try to clarify it  :)

Comment: Excellent update to your question! I know you said you read the docs, chapters 4, 7 and 8 provide some concepts that get at these more complicated peer to peer topologies, also there is a repository of open source communication patterns linked in there that could be helpful. Designing these things is definitely complex at best, though. I'll post a partial answer, and then flesh it out later when I have time with socket choices and communication strategies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're somewhat misunderstanding the ZMQ socket types, protocols, and addressing.  I'll try to address that first, so that you might be able to move forward.

ZMQ absolutely abstracts away the nitty gritty details of using network protocols like TCP, but you're still going to have to tell it to use TCP when you're communicating over a network, and you're still going to be using good 'ol IP addresses or DNS names to connect your peers to each other.

So, for your case, each worker node will have an IP address and/or DNS name.  If you know these ahead of time, you don't even need to ask the server/master for them, you can just connect immediately to the IP address from one worker to the other.  If, instead, the server/master has this information and the workers don't at startup time, then the worker can request a list of IP addresses and the master can just send it over... then it's connecting to the IP address of the peer just like it does, for instance, when it connects to the master.

server

```
// obviously this code will change depending on the language/binding that you use
// this is psuedo-code
server = new zmq.socket('ROUTER');
server.bind('tcp://10.20.30.40:55555');
```

worker1

```
worker1 = new zmq.socket('REQ');
worker1.connect('tcp://10.20.30.40:55555');
```

worker2

```
worker2 = new zmq.socket('REQ');
worker2.connect('tcp://10.20.30.40:55555');
```

... You indicate that `PAIR` sockets seemed to make the most sense to you to connect the workers, but they are only appropriate for communication from within a single multi-threaded application from one thread to another, so it's not what you're looking for here.  Instead, you probably want each worker to have its own router socket, and you can create new req sockets as need to connect to each peer:

worker1

```
worker1 = new zmq.socket('REQ');
peer1 = new zmq.socket('ROUTER');
peer1.bind('tcp://10.20.30.41:44444');
worker1.connect('tcp://10.20.30.40:55555');

peers = worker1.send('tell me my peers');
for (i=0; i<peers.length; i++) {
    peer_array[i] = new zmq.socket('REQ');
    peer_array[i].connect('tcp://' . peers[i]);
}
```

worker2

```
worker2 = new zmq.socket('REQ');
peer2 = new zmq.socket('ROUTER');
peer2.bind('tcp://10.20.30.42:33333');
worker2.connect('tcp://10.20.30.40:55555');

peers = worker2.send('tell me my peers');
for (i=0; i<peers.length; i++) {
    peer_array[i] = new zmq.socket('REQ');
    peer_array[i].connect('tcp://' . peers[i]);
}
```

... what's going on here is that each worker is setting up a request socket to connect to the router of each other worker.  The server would be sending back a list of strings of the form ipaddress:port.

Without knowing what type of information is being passed around from server to worker or from worker to worker, it's impossible to give better advice than that for which sockets you might choose, but at minimum this assumes a client/server request/reply type of system.

We can go a lot deeper about why you'd make these particular choices if you're interested, or if you're still stuck please just let me know in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer! To answer some of the questions you've raised: I don't know the network in advance, so discovery is what why i want to do here. The network will not change after that. And the only thing that's gonna be transmitted are lots and lots of floats (i'm doing fluid simulation).

Comment: Another thing that just came to my mind: Is it just "bad style" to use PAIR sockets for the worker-worker-connection or are there some other drawbacks? I figured since the worker-relations never change, i might as well use PAIR-socket for each one, because it saves some logic and potential errors there.

Comment: Well, PAIR is explicitly discouraged for anything other than inter-thread communication in the docs, I don't recall how much detail they give as to why and I haven't looked at the source behind it, but I can tell you this: PAIR loses the ZMQ "magic" that automatically reconnects the sockets in the case of any network issues that causes a loss of connection.  That in and of itself is reason to avoid it for anything other than what it's designed for.

Comment: Ah okay, yeah that disconnect thing makes sense. Your solution also seems to be easier^^

Comment: When you stick with a REQ-ROUTER combination, it is fairly easy.  I might write up a question/answer for how to do a ROUTER-ROUTER combo, which is easily the most flexible combination you can use in ZMQ, you just have to manage details that are otherwise handled natively by the library.  Generally you can make one of the recommended socket pairs work for you as you can in this case.